# VideoJS/HTML5 Video -Stop all videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, html5-video

I am using VideoJS's WordPress plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/videojs-html5-video-player-for-wordpress/) to display self hosted videos on a website. Videos are listed in a gallery and each video opens in a modal window when clicked. This is working great, but when the modal window is closed, the video continues to play in the background.

Is there a way to stop or terminate all HTML5 videos on a page using jQuery? My thinking is that I will run this "stop" function (if it exists) when a modal window is closed.

Thanks.

Comment: did you even look at the docs for video.js? The methods are described in the API. Read the docs for the modal to find how to hook into the close callback

Comment: I had read the docs and tried the methods but I must have been doing something wrong. I got it working anyway by adding $(".video-js")[0].player.pause(); to my close modal function. :)